# Update external table when word press user changes profile info

Tags: php, wordpress

We have an external table of our website users that we would like to update when the user changes something in their profile.  Currently, we sync the databases, but now we need faster transfer.

I've searched stack and google, and can't find anything?

Any help or links is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a hook:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/

```
add_action('profile_update', 'force_sync_profile');
 
function force_sync_profile($userId, $oldUserData) {
    $newData = get_userdata($userId);
    // Call an API or something to sync new/old data
}
```